# Eclipse Hangs On DDMS post-create-init

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed android adt 21 plugins in eclipse helios. All was going well before it. After adt installation, eclipse hangs on DDMS post-create-init. Please help me to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem? Can you please give us a good explanation and any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed before on StackOverflow. This answer might help you: [Eclipse Hangs in DDMS post-create init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677679/eclipse-hangs-in-ddms-post-create-init)